# Struts2-Tiles2-Xform---- ${body},${footer},${header} values are empty

Tags: struts2, tiles

I have struts2.xml definition like this:

```
<action name="/template">
   <param name="body">/common/test.jsp</param>
   <param name="header">/page/header.do</param>
   <param name="footer">/page/footer.do</param>
   <result name="success" type="tiles">/test.tiles</result>
</action>
```

In Tiles2:

```
<definition name=".default" template="/Template.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/page/header.do"/>
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="/page/menu.do/>
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/page/home.do"/>
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/page/footer.do"/>
</definition>

<definition name="/test.tiles" extends=".default">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="body123"/>
</definition>
```

Xform:

```
<div id="header">
  <include page="${header}"/>
</div>

<div id="body">
  <include page="${body}"/>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  <include page="${footer}"/>
</div>
```

I can't get the values(`${body}`, `${footer}`, `{header}`) here. Whenever I requested this xflow I'm getting the blank page.

Web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher> 
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher> 
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Please let me know if anything wrong with my configuration.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: Your doing a few weird things. When you call a tiles result you should be rendering a view. It's not made to be the foundation of a component based framework. 1) You shouldn't be calling actions from the view (.do extensions) 2) Attributes are inserted using tiles tags not EL expressions. 3) You seem to be using include directives, which tiles is supposed to replace and largely undermines the benefits of tiles.

Comment: Also there is a struts2-tiles3 plugin... Could be worth going with that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm using struts2 tiles plugin. Everything is working fine now.